# RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.' RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0' in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-requests-html

I am trying to run below python script in Google Cloud Function.

Runtime : Python 3.8

Entry point : hello_world

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
def hello_world(request):
    session = HTMLSession()
        
    r = session.get('https://translate.google.com')
    r.html.render()  
    app = r.html.find('#yDmH0d')
    for value in app:
        return value.text[:10]
```

Triggering event: {}

When I am testing this function in google cloud platform, I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, 
    in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, 
    in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, 
    in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, 
    in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, 
    in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, 
    in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 87, 
    in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 6, 
    in hello_world r.html.render() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, 
    in render self.browser = self.session.browser # Automatically create a event loop and browser File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 727, 
    in browser self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, 
    in get_event_loop raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.' RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, 
    in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, 
    in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, 
    in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, 
    in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, 
    in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, 
    in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 87, 
    in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 6, 
    in hello_world r.html.render() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, 
    in render self.browser = self.session.browser # Automatically create a event loop and browser File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 727,
    in browser self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, 
    in get_event_loop raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.' RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Request-HTML](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) site it says that only `Python 3.6` is supported, so it's not possible to run it on Cloud Functions.

You may want to try another web scraper in this case.

Comment: I have python 3.9 in my local machine and request_html is working on it. I tried all python options on google cloud platform. It is not working in any of them. Can you tell me why it is working on local machine with higher python version?

Comment: @Akash I get your point and indeed it may work on higher versions, but it's not guaranteed. In this case, Request-HTML has requirement for the version 3.6 and because Cloud Functions runs on a different version, 3.8, it explains why, unfortunately, this won't work.